# Create a function that capitalizes the first letter of each word and transforms all other letters to lowercase

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop, increment

I have this exercise who capitalize the first character in given sentence.Please i can't understood what "i - 1" and str[i - 1] means

```
#include <stdio.h>
char* ft_strcapitalize(char *str)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (str[i])
    {
        if ((i - 1 == 0 && str[i] != ' ')
            || (str[i - 1] >= 'a' && str[i - 1] <= 'z')
            || (str[i - 1] >= 'A' && str[i - 1] <= 'Z')
            || (str[i - 1] >= '1' && str[i - 1] <= '9'))
        {
        }
        else if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z')
                str[i] -= 32;
        i++;
    }
    return (str);
}

int main(void)
{
    char s[] = "salut, comment  tu vas ? 42mots quarante-deux; cinquante+et+un";
    ft_strcapitalize(s);
    printf("%s", s);
}
```

Comment: `str[i - 1]` means previous character, which is a problem when you're at index zero, but what actually happens for you, and what did you expect to happen?

Comment: It's just a bug, the code is incorrectly written and there's nothing to understand. It's senseless to access `str[i - 1]` when `i` is zero, which this code likely does.

Comment: The code work perfectly, it returned the first character on each word capitalized, but I’m get confused about how he do that, I tried to initiate the i to 0 but the first word “salut” didn’t get capitalized, can any one write a meaningful code to do that ?

Comment: It is accessing the array out-of-bounds, which is [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). It might work.

Comment: "Create a function that capitalizes the first letter of each word and transforms all other letters to lowercase" and "this exercise who capitalize the first character in given sentence." are contradictory. Please define clearly what exactly your aim is.

Answer (score 1):

> Please i can't understood what "i - 1" and str[i - 1] means

`str[i - 1]` attempts to access the previous character in the string - the one before `str[i]`.  It is bad code to use when `i==0`.

---

> Create a function that capitalizes the first letter of each word and transforms all other letters to lowercase

Keep a state variable that identifies the next character may start a sentence.  Use character handling functions from `<ctype.h>`.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

char* ft_strcapitalize(char *str) {
  size_t i = 0;
  bool start = true; 
  while (str[i]) {
    if (start && isalpha(str[i])) {
      str[i] = toupper(str[i]);
      start = false;
    } else {
      str[i] = tolower(str[i]);
      // TBD: Adjust 'start' detection as needed.
      if (str[i] == '.' || str[i] == '?' || str[i] == '!') {
        start = true;
      }
    }
    i++;
  }
  return str;
}
```